# Javascript keep getting undefined after function - prompt

Tags: javascript, function, undefined

So I`m working ona simple JS code. We just started to learn about functions.
I need to make a function named "printStars".

I need to take a number from the user and accourding that number print "*".

This is what I did:

```js
    <script>   
        function printStars()
        {
            var n = Number(prompt("Insert number of stars:","0.."));
            for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
            {
                document.write("*");
            }
        }
        var stars = printStars();
        document.write(stars);
    </script>
```

In the end I get my result with a minus of getting "undefined".
I would love to get some help, and an explanation why is keep happening.

Thanks guys!

Comment: Your "printStars" function does not return any value, so after you call it the variable "stars" will be `undefined`.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need this

```
document.write(stars);
```

You just need this:

```
// This will make you function to be evaluated and 
// the code in your function will be executed.
printStars();
```

```js
function printStars()
{
    var n = Number(prompt("Insert number of stars:","0.."));
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        document.write("*");
    }
}

printStars();
```

Comment: I have another question.
I need to make a function named getNum:

the user need to insert 2 numbers between 2 - 20 and I need to return the value.
plus I need to make the user insert only numbers between 2 and 20.

Comment: @PeterToth sure thing. What's up?

Comment: This is what I did:

    <script>
        function getNumber(x,y)
        {
            x = Number(prompt("enter:"));
            y = Number(prompt("enter:"));

            while (x < 2 || x > 20 || y < 2 || y > 20)
            {
                x = Number(prompt("enter:"));
                y = Number(prompt("enter:"));
            }
            return x;
            return y;
        }

        getNumber();
    </script>

Answer (score 1):

[jsfiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/kasperfish/jnyxzkpb/1/)

```
function printStars(){
    var n = prompt("Insert number of stars:","0..");
    var stars='';
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++){
        stars+='*';

    }
    $('body').html(stars) //jsfiddle does not allow document.write()
    //document.write(stars);
}

//call the function
printStars();
```